# Writing a Slick query that returns a case class that's a combination of tables

Tags: scala, slick, slick-3.0, typesafe

I'm using Slick 3.1 and have the following setup:

```
case class Part1(...)
case class Part2(...)
case class Both(p1: Part1, p2 : Part2)
class Part1Row extends Table[Part1]
class Part2Row extends Table[Part2]
val p1s = TableQuery[Part1Table]
val p2s = TableQuery[Part2Table]
```

I'd like to build a query like this:

```
val query = 
    for {
       p1 <- p1s
       p2 <- p2s
   } yield Both(p1, p2)
```

That would allow:

```
query.filter(_.p1.attr === "Foo")
```

Is this possible?  If so how?

p1 and p2 are of type Part1Row and Part2Row not Part1 and Part2, so they don't fit the Both case class.  Furthermore, it seems like I want something like a Rep[Both], not a naked Both.